# How to test if a record was created in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit

I am coming from Laravel and new to ASP.net MVC. In Laravel I used to do this to assert if a record was created in database or not:

```php
public function test_a_user_is_created_in_database()
{
    // Arrange
    // Act

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
        'email' => 'sally@example.com'
    ]);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in Xunit?

Comment: Usually we mock testing the database as its an external resource or these days we use In-Memory DBs for testing. When you start testing the database calls that's more of an integration test. To do it you'll need the SqlConnection or whatever database provider you're using to test if a record exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way to accomplish the goal, but this works fine for my purposes:

```
public static void AssertDatabaseHas(string table, Dictionary<string, object> filters, 
    bool assertMissing = false) {

    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand()) {
        cmd.Connection = GetDbConnection();

        // Assemble the WHERE part of the query
        // and add parameters to the command.
        var filterStr = "1 = 1";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in filters) {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value.ToString())) {
                filterStr += " AND " + item.Key + " IS NULL";
            } else {
                filterStr += " AND " + item.Key + " = @" + item.Key;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }

        // Put the query together.
        cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT 1 FROM {0} WHERE {1}", table, filterStr);

        // Execute the query and check the result.
        using (MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            if (assertMissing) {
                Assert.False(rdr.HasRows, "Undesired record exists.");
            } else {
                Assert.True(rdr.HasRows, "Desired record does not exist.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A reverse of the function is also easily added:

```
public static void AssertDatabaseMissing(string table, Dictionary<string, object> filters) {
    AssertDatabaseHas(table, filters, assertMissing: true);
}
```

When both are added to a MyCustomAssertions class, they can be called like this:

```
public void test_a_user_is_created_in_database()
{
    MyCustomAssertions.AssertDatabaseHas("users", new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "email", "sally@example.com" }
    });

    MyCustomAssertions.AssertDatabaseMissing("users", new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "email", "sally@example.com" }, { "id", "10" }
    });
}
```

Note:

- The code can be easily adapted for MSTest if you happen to be using that; all you need to change is `Assert.False` to `Assert.IsFalse` and the same for True.
- This example uses MySQL but can probably be modified for any engine. For Npgsql (PostgreSQL) for example, change `MySqlCommand` to `NpgsqlCommand` and `MySqlDataReader` to `NpgsqlDataReader`.

Answer (score 0):

That is an integration test.

You probably don’t want to do an integration test, typically in .net and unit test, you would use something like FakeItEasy or Moq to provide the correctly typed data, so that the code under test is supplied with the data matching the scenario you want to test in a unit test.  If you are testing whether a user is present, you would set it up so that the called to load the data returns the appropriate response, and if you were testing what happens when the user is present you would provide data and calls that return the data appropriate to the user you want to test.

Integration test might be appropriate when integrating a web service, and you don’t quite know for sure what it will return, but if you are using something like dbcontext and entity framework (and you probably should be) then there’s no question about what successfully loading a user should return.